# Play second audio after the first has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have the following HTML:

```
<audio autoplay id="background_audio">
      <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The code above plays some music in the background.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

This code plays a swoosh sound when the user enters the page.

And I have the following JS:

```
<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');

    document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
    {
        e = e || window.event;
        audio.muted = !audio.muted;
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>
```

This code is used to mute the background music when the user clicks on a certain div.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q907hho/).

The link to the project I'm working at is [here](https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.html).

I'm trying to create a script that won't play the `audio` located in the `background_audio` id **until** a certain ammount of seconds (for example's sake, 5s) have passed so that the swoosh sound can finish playing before starting the music.

I did some research on SO and Google and camed to the conclusion that some use of `preventDefault()` would be the solution however I fail to implement the solution.

How can I make the music in the `background_audio` id after the swoosh sound have finished playing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onended` [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events), play your second audio after first one ended.

```js
var audio1 = document.getElementById("another_audio");
audio1.onended = function() {
  console.log('Playing background audio')
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("background_audio");
  audio2.play();
};
```

```html
<audio id="background_audio">
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/hol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio autoplay id="another_audio">
  <source src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/sounds/swoosh-enter.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```